# Android reCaptcha forces orientation in portrait

Tags: android, recaptcha, safetynet

I'm developing an Android app that needs to validate user with reCaptcha and I'm occurred on strange behaviour: if screen orientation is in landscape, tapping button that fires reCaptcha API orientation changhes to portrait and then back to landscape.

There is a way to fix this? I'm not found any documentation about this...

Here is API from SafetyNet lib:

```
SafetyNet.getClient(this).verifyWithRecaptcha(ReCaptcha.RECAPTCHA_APP_KEY)
```

Version:

```
 implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0")
```

Answer (score -1):

When you rotate your activity gets refreshed

You need to declare android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in activity tag

```
<activity
         android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

this will avoid activity refresh
I hope this will help

Comment: It turns out that i'm not rotating the screen, is reCaptcha that automatically force this behaviour!